# How to connect to mongo db of a meteor app on a remote server using robomongo?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have been trying to connect to mongo db of a meteor app running on a remote server using robomongo v0.8.4. I tried setting the IP address of the server hosting the meteor app in the 'Address' field, 3002 in the port number field in the 'Connection' tab. In the Authentication tab,checked the 'Perform Authentication' checkbox, set the database name as 'meteor', and no username or password are kept blank.

When I try to connect, I get the following error,

```
Cannot connect to MongoDB
error: Unable to connect to MongoDB
```

Am I missing something here ? I went through other related posts in stack, but couldn't find
a solution to this specific problem.

Please help me out with issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you ran Meteor with `meteor` and not from a bundled node version, the IP address is bound to `127.0.0.1`, so you would not be able to connect to it remotely, only locally.

Find the IP address of your machine using a tool like `ipconfig` and bind the IP address meteor runs in onto it instead:

```
BIND_IP=192.168.x.x meteor
```

Then you should be able to access it with robomongo.

You should only use this type of 'development mode' meteor for development. For production, its recommended you bundle your app and use your own seperate mongodb server.

Comment: I am running the app using meteorite. Where should I be putting the BIND_IP statement ?

Comment: use mrt instead of meteor, its just setting `BIND_IP` as the environment variable. You could also use `export BIND_IP=x.x.x.x`

Comment: So what is the answer, is it to run mrt BIND_IP=X.X.X.X from the command line?

Comment: @JoePrivett yes, exactly as in the answer, the environmental variables come before the command so BIND_IP=XXX mrt

Comment: This didn't work for me. My Windows PC IP was 192.168.0.5, my Virtual Machine IP was 192.168.56.111, so I used 'BIND_IP=192.168.0.5 mrt' on the command line, then 192.168.56.111:3001 in Robomongo - what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `METEOR_MONGO_BIND_IP=192.168.1.3,127.0.0.1 meteor run` works. make sure to put both internal and external ip so meteor will also see it

Answer (score 1):

You must bind mongo to the external ip, because its localhost by default

```
METEOR_MONGO_BIND_IP=127.0.0.1,192.168.x.x meteor run
```

Be sure to also have the local internal ip also delimited by commas o meteor can see it too. This works for me using MongoCompass.

Connect to it using host 192.168.x.x port 3001

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Robo 3T v 1.1.1 , i used dyxj's advice (found here https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up-legacy/issues/1122  ) to connect from Mac OSX to Meteor Mongo running on VirtualBox Ubuntu.

I start Meteor using command : `meteor --settings settings.json`

Steps :

1. connect to "localhost" and port 3001
2. use the SSH function in Robo 3T
3. fill in auth as required by remote server (ex. username / password)

Do note that I had to install "openssh-server" on my Ubuntu instance to get this to work.